# Autofac registrations present but servicelocator throws ComponentNotRegisteredException

Tags: exception, autofac, registration

Here is some sample code

```
public void RegisterDependencies()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            ConfigureModules(builder);
            ConfigureProfiles(builder);

            var container = builder.Build();

            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new AutofacServiceLocator(container));
        }

protected virtual void ConfigureModules(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            var assemblies = GetAssemblies();
            {
                builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(assemblies);
            }
        }

        protected virtual void ConfigureProfiles(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            var profiles = GetTypes<Profile>();

            builder.RegisterInstance(new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddMaps(profiles)).CreateMapper())
                .As<IMapper>();
        }
```

The GetAssemblies() method loads and returns an array of assemblies referenced by the app. All the modules are registered and showing up in the servicelocator. However, when trying to resolve an interface using the following code, I get the ComponentNotRegisteredException:

```
_dlMembershipParserService =
                ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IDLMembershipParserService>();
```

Here is a sample of one of the Modules:

```
public class ServiceModule : Autofac.Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterType<DLMembershipParserService>().As<IDLMembershipParserService>();
            builder.RegisterType<DLMembershipExporterService>().As<IDLMembershipExporterService>();
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have any ideas? The assemblies are loaded and there is only one assembly for each dll being loaded.

I've also tried the following code with the same result:

```
protected virtual void ConfigureModules(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            var modules = GetTypes<IModule>().Select(m => (IModule)Activator.CreateInstance(m));

            foreach (var module in modules)
            {
                builder.RegisterModule(module);
            }
        }
```

But the only thing that works is a had reference to the Module, like so:

`builder.RegisterModule<ServiceModule>();`

But this isn't what I want. I need to be able to add modules and have them discovered by the app.

I appreciate any insight into this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I discovered what I need to do, from a .NET Core point of view, in order to discover and load assemblies dynamically from .NET Core.

There is a nuget package required to Load .NET Core assemblies so that all the registered types can be resolved at runtime. The package is called System.Runtime.Loader.

Once installed, I was able to successfully discover assemblies based on Type information, then load, register and resolve types at runtime.

Here is some sample code:

```
public override Type[] GetTypes<T>()
{
    var assemblyPath = _assemblyHelper.GetEntryAssemblyLocation();
    var path = _pathHelper.GetDirectoryName(assemblyPath);

    var files = _fileHelper.GetFiles(path, "Tss.DLMembership.*.dll");

    return files.SelectMany(file => _assemblyHelper.LoadFile(file).GetTypes()
        .Where(t => typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(t) && !t.IsInterface && !t.IsAbstract))
    .ToArray();
}

public class AssemblyHelper : IAssemblyHelper
{
    public string GetEntryAssemblyLocation()
    {
        return AppContext.BaseDirectory;
    }

    public Assembly LoadFile(string fileName)
    {
        return AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(fileName);
    }
}
```

This solved my issue with resolving registered types after loading the assemblies and registering types.

Answer (score 0):

> The GetAssemblies() method loads and returns an array of assemblies referenced by the app.

Are you calling `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` or dynamically loading assemblies into your app? If yes, check if the assemblies containing `DLMembershipParserService` and its dependent types are loaded by the time you call `GetAssemblies()`.

Note that not all **referenced** assemblies are loaded at app start. Assemblies are loaded on first use. That might be the reason if you reference the module in your code, it works.

If you need to forcibly load all referenced assemblies, you will have to use `Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies` method to find out all referenced assemblies and load them into your app.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getreferencedassemblies?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: I am using this line to load the assemblies used by RegisterModules:

Comment: return files.Select(file => _assemblyHelper.LoadFile(file))
  .ToArray();

Comment: If your assemblies are all loaded, you could set break points into your modules and see if they are hit. Also, if you check the error message of the **most** inner exception of `ComponentNotRegisteredException`, you will find out which service wasn't registered.

Comment: The inner most exception states that the service has not been registered, however, break points are hit in both modules being loaded...I must be missing something?

Comment: Sometimes a `ComponentNotRegisteredException` could be raised on dependent service not registered. E.g. `Class1` uses `Class2`, however `Class2` is not registered. You probably need to read the full message of the most inner exception and figure out which constructor, which types the activator was using to create your service instance. And why it failed.

Comment: Here is the exact message from the inner most exception:

Comment: The requested service 'Tss.DLMembership.Services.IDLMembershipParserService' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.

Comment: StackTrace of inner most exception:

Comment: at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType)
   at Autofac.Extras.CommonServiceLocator.AutofacServiceLocator.DoGetInstance(Type serviceType, String key)
   at CommonServiceLocator.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type serviceType, String key)

Comment: Irony is that these services only have default constructors, so no parameters!

Comment: That's weird. I can't think of anything obvious wrong tbh apart from the assemblies not loaded correctly based on the fact that if you directly references `ServiceModule` in your code it works. I have a local app which loads `Assembly` using `Assembly.LoadFile` and then use `RegisterAssemblyModules` to register all modules in the assembly, and it just works. Crazy thoughts are (this happened once to me), the module has referenced a different version of `IDLMembershipParserService` than where `IDLMembershipParserService` is being resolved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209805/discussion-between-user953710-and-weichch).